# Using magic to replicate modern technology

Tags: magic, modern

In a fantasy world that operates with magic, can wizards and mages use their abilities to replicate modern technology? For example either a flashlight or a modern aircraft? How would they accomplish this? I don't have boundaries for the magic of this world yet i just wanna know if it can work

Edit: what if a boeing 747 ends up on this fantasy world, would they have been able to mass produce more boeing's?

Comment: why shouldn't magic work? magic is not bound to the laws of physics..

Comment: You just need a starting magic system that is self-consistent, and derive technologies from that. Like using D&D, a continual light spell at the bottom of a tube is a flashlight.

Comment: Well, it is your world so you make the rules. For example, the *Flintstones* replicated modern technology with stone age tools and friendly domesticated dinosaurs. On the other hand, if magic is available then many modern tools would be utterly useless; who needs a washing machine when one can simply *will* the dirt away?

Comment: @AlexP, ooh, ooh, I know! Because the washing machine is what "houses" the spell. Duh . Mages sell washing machines to folks that can't do magic. (Seriously, that *exact* question came up in a story I'm writing — [note](/questions/160428). Yes, a magic user *could* "simply *will* the dirt away"... but why bother, when they can just toss dirty clothes in a washing machine and not have to exert themselves? Mind, the washing machine *does* use magic instead of soap.)

Comment: While I disagree with that *specific* example, the overall sentiment is correct. Two items that *don't* exist in my story, at least in households, are dishwashers and lawn mowers. To wash dishes, you just run some water over them, and they are pretty much instantly clean and sanitary, and as soon as you take away the water, *dry*. To cut grass, there is a stick you drag over your lawn (on wheels or runners) that cuts the grass where it touches the stick. Depending on how your magic works, there will surely be other examples! (Mine is metabolism-powered, which severely limits its power budget.)

Comment: Unfortunatley the edit has not helped; rather than making it more focussed, you've just added a further question. Please review the part of the [help] relating to how to write an [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question and have a good think about how to focus your efforts to best effect here.

Comment: This question is too open-ended if you're asking about a magic system that can replicate modern technology without giving any restrictions for the magic system. Magic systems are incredibly diverse.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, if you do it correctly.**

They'd likely use a combination of magics with effects similar to what you want. For example a cannon could be made through the use of explosion magic instead of gunpowder. A blowdrier could be made through a small electric spell, a simple resistance that heats up and wind magic (substitute the resistance with fire magic though and you might get something closer to a flamethrower). The main differences between you magic tools is that most physical and chemical reactions that allow them to work would be substituted by combinations of magic spells happening simultaneously to reach the desired effect. Cars and other vehicles could be simply modified golems (artificial beings) with wheel like structures for locomotion and internal space for the passengers, and a system similar to GPS could be achieved through the use of multiple flying golems communicating with the car golems, again using messaging spells, on which routes are available and how is the road. With soft magic systems very little is truly impossible.

Regarding your aircrafts, you could make an intelligent golem with a plane shape and moving wing parts, grant it the ability to use wind magic as a means of propulsion and allow it to communicate to towers through message magic. If your golem is "programmed" to do the correct calculations and is built correctly you'll get your aircraft. 
Alternatively, you could use programmed magic crystals as board computers and controls; and use powerful wind magic for the propulsion system and to keep the chambers pressurized, along with glass (that's important for the pilots and passengers). That way you'd get something decently close.

Finnaly, the Boeing. If they already didn't have some kind of magic parallel to the plane, they'd likely take a while to, but I think they'd manage. The main issue here is that, unless the plane is kept on good state and the magicians can observe it working properly, they'll basically need to go through an alternative version of the entire history of the planes to reach the knowledge necessary to replicate the Boeing and its capabilities.

Summing it up: its magic, magic is the best way to justify things simply because, unless it has rules saying it can't do something, the answer to "Can magic do this? " will always be "yes". The real challenge here will come after you define your magic system and its rules, which is when it will gain limitations that could interfere with this machinery replication.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. How they would accomplish it is a whole other topic that could fill a thousand pages trying to go into specifics. The wonderful thing about introducing magic in a world that's your own creation is your ability to allow it to work however YOU want it to. Taking that into consideration, of course modern technology can be replicated. However, I don't understand what you mean when you ask how they would accomplish it. This should be based on the rules of the magic system that you create, which you can shape in any way that you wish. It seems like the magic of your world (is it your world?) is very undeveloped. You should start by creating its structure and seeing where modern technology fits within that structure.

I will add that magic not bound by a system or rules establishes a very sloppy foundation. It's very lazy and can induce massive inconsistencies across the board. Not to mention plot holes in stories. Also, keep in mind that magic itself can be just a different form of technology. Magic usually makes things more effective, more purposeful, more dynamic, more convenient, more diverse and more productive. Does technology not do the same thing? Would these magic users even want to use something as "primitive" and "human" as modern technology? Would it be in their best interest?

There's a lot of questions here, and your question is very broad and invokes a lot of would-be assumptions and head-scratching. If you can provide more detail, I'll be more than happy to provide a more definitive answer.